# Integrability of distributions which are invariant under the isometry group

Tags: riemannian-geometry, foliations

Let  $(M.g)$  be  a Riemannian  manifold  and  $D$  is  a  distribution on $M$. Assume  that $D$  is  invariant under  the  action of the  isometry  group  of  $M$.

Under which  conditions such  $D$ is an  integrable  distribution?What  is  an  example  of  a non integrable distribution with this  invariant  property?

In the  case  of  integrability,  under what  conditions  the  leaves  of  corresponding  foliation  are  totally geodesic?

The  motivation comes from the  case  $\mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus \{0\}$  with the standard  metrics.  there  is  only  one  distribution  with this  property, which is integrable.

Comment: Take any non-integrable $D$, and perturb any $g$ to have trivial isometry group...

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler  Thank  you  for  your  comment.For example  what  is  a  rigid  perturbation  of  the  usual  metric  of  the  plane?

Comment: The plane is maybe not so relevant here, since all rank 1 distributions are integrable.

Comment: You might look at the Berger metrics on the odd dimensional spheres: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berger%27s_sphere

Comment: @BenMcKay  Yes but I  am  asking  for  rigidity(trivial  isometry). Otherwise  we can  ask the  same rigidity  question  for  "space".  BTW what type  of  compact  Riemanian  manifold  has  trivial  isomeetry group?

Comment: @AliTaghavi $\rho(x,y)(dx^2+dy^2)$ where $\rho>0$ has no nontrivial symmetries? [Metrics without isometries are generic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.0182).

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler The  poincare  upper plane has  the conformal  metric  but the  isometry is  not  trivial. May  be  you  are  considering  some  extra  conditions  on $\rho$?

Comment: Pretty much any $\rho$ will do. E.g. start with the constant 1 and add small bumps localized at the vertices of some irregular polygon.

Comment: Your questions remind me the topic of "polar actions".  A $G$-action (by isometries) is called polar (or better) locally polar if the distribution (on the open set of principal orbits) of normal spaces is integrable.  Most $G$-actions are not polar. For example most representations of a compact Lie group induce a non polar action on a sphere. Dadok's theorem tells that the polar ones are those having the same orbits of a so called s-representation. For this topic see Bernd-Console-Olmos' book "Submanifolds and holonomy".

Comment: @Holonomia  Thank  you  very  much  for your very interesting  comment,  the  concept  of  polar  action  and  the  book "submanifold and  holonomy"

Comment: @BenMcKay  Thank  you  very  much  for  your very interesting  comment s, in particular the reference  on the Berger  metrics